# URL error missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset' when trying to access from browser

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to follow this tutorials:
https://djangobook.com/django-views-dynamic-content/

URL page is like below

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
]
```

And the associate view is like below:

```
def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be  %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

however when i try to access any URL like below it gives me error. 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/time/plus/5/

[image]

I am seeing following error.  I am not passing the offset  from browser URL to view. 
In the console it shows following error:

```
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: hours_ahead() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'
[01/Oct/2018 13:29:12] "GET /time/plus/3/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62628
```

Comment: Rewrite your url to `url(r'^time/plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead)`

Comment: It works but i am confused. When to Use URL and when to use path?
I tried to do the same thing with a different url it does not work:
          url(r'^welcome/(?P<name>)/$', welcome_name)

The view is a follow :
def welcome_name(request, name):

    html = "<html><body> hello  %s, Welcome to my home</body></html>" % name
    return HttpResponse(html)


I am seeing error :
ject\pages\urls.py", line 28
    url(r'^welcome/(?P<name>)/$', welcome_name)

Comment: you can use both (and interleaved as well). The point is that you did not specify that your capture group was a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
    url(r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    url(r'^time/plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
    ]
```

Comment: I got that but how that ?P works? 
if i try this, url(r'^welcome/(?P<name>)/$', welcome_name) why it does not work

Comment: @Rana: because you did not specify a regex part in the parameter, only  parameter name. And the `name` this can only be the empty string. For a name, you might want to add something like `(?P<name>\w+)`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing more reading and the knowledge above i found that path is more readable and easy to do. Path is also more python way which included in python 2.0
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#whats-new-2-0

For the first question answer easier:

```
path('time/plus/<int:offset1>/', hours_ahead),
```

For the second answer it is:

```
path('welcome/<name>/', welcome_name),
```